# Vectorization with multiple rows and columns of dataframe instead of one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently working on building a csv file that include historical stock info, while not only includes historical prices, but momentum indicators. I've successfully added indicators by looping through an entire dataframe (w/ > 25,000,000 rows), but it takes too long (30 - 36 h).

What I'm trying to accomplish: I'd like start with the the 3 day high:

`high = stock_df.loc[x+1:x+4, "High"].max(axis=0)`

and divide that by the day 0 low:

`low =  stock_df.loc[x, "Low"]`

without iterating through entire loop like as shown below:

```
stock_ticker_list = df.Symbol.unique()
for ticker in stock_ticker_list:
    #return dataframe thats historical infor for one stock
    print(ticker)
    stock_df = df.loc[df.Symbol == ticker]
    start = stock_df.index[stock_df['Symbol'] == ticker][0]
    for x in range(start, start + len(stock_df) - 2):
        try:
            high = stock_df.loc[x+1:x+4, "High"].max(axis=0)  
            low =  stock_df.loc[x, "Low"] 
            df2.loc[x,"H/L"] = high/low
        except:
            df2.loc[x,"H/L"] = pd.NA
```

I've look through the documentation and found methods like pandas.Series.pct_change and pandas.Series.div but it does not appear as though these functions will work without me also creating a column for the 3 day high. I tried to create a column for the three day high

```
s = stock_df["High"] 
stock_df['Three_day_high'] = max([s.diff(-1),s.diff(-2),s.diff(-3)]) + s
```

but got a ValueError (`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`)

Answer (score 0):

Consider windowing operations: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/window.html

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# for testing, have generated a 50 million row dataframe with random numbers in the range 500 to 1500
l1 = np.round(500 + 1000 * np.random.rand(5000000,1), 0)
df = pd.DataFrame(l1, columns = ["Val"])

# rolling window applied to the Val column
%timeit df["Val"].rolling(window=3).max() / df["Val"]  # optional timing function
df["H"] = df["Val"].rolling(window=3, closed = 'left').max() # optional to show 3 day high
df["HL"] = df["Val"].rolling(window=3, closed = 'left').max() / df["Val"]
df[:7]
```

1.07 s ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
[image]